# Android ListView onItemClick show Popup on exact position

Tags: java, dynamic, android-listview, position, popupwindow

I have a `PopupWindow` which is shown as a drop down when I click a `Item` on my `ListView`:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_click_menu, null);
            final PopupWindow mypopupWindow = new PopupWindow(v,300, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            mypopupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, -153, 0);
        }
```

The result is this:

[image: ListView with two Items, the last one is clicked]

My question is: I want to have a dynamic position of my pop up. So if I click on the middle of the `Item` then it should be shown in the middle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a `TouchListener`:

```
list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                positionX = (int) event.getX();

                return false; // not consumed; forward to onClick
            }
        });
```

Then you have the exact x-position and you can move the `PopupWindow` by `onItemClick`:

```
mypopupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, positionX, 0);
```